# Changing CSS of a property via JQuery when toggling sidebar does not work

Tags: jquery, css

In my rails application, I am trying to change the margin of my div depending if sidebar is collapsed or not. I am using the `.css()` method of JQuery and I can't seem to make it work.

Here is my JS snippet:

```
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function(){
  $('.openbtn').on('click', function() {
    // This toggles my sidebar
    $('.collapsed-sidebar').toggleClass('displaynone');

    // Checks if the sidebar is collapsed
    if($('.collapsed-sidebar').is(":visible")){

      // So far I have verified that it triggers this alert
      // when I collapse my sidebar
      alert("collapsed sidebar is visible");

      // Class that I am trying to change the CSS Property
      $('.signedin').css({
        'margin-right': '50px !important'
      });
    }

  });
});
```

Here is my HTML structure:

```
<body>
    <div class="ui sidebar vertical left menu visible very thin icon">
        <div class="collapsed-sidebar displaynone"> // This is the element that I toggle
             // Sidebar content here
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pusher">
        <div class="row content">
            <div class="signedin"> // Element that I am trying to change the property
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body
```

Here is the CSS of my sidebar:

```
.displaynone {
  display: none !important;
}

.ui.sidebar.vertical.menu {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.1s;
  transition-duration: 0.1s;
}
```

Comment: You need to share css of sidebar as well...

Comment: @Khan already edited my question to include the CSS of sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.signedin').css("margin-right","50px !important");
```

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by 'another method'? So far I can still verify that all the function calls up to the `alert` are being executed.

Comment: Did you try ('.signedin').click() and then alert something? If it works, I think your problem is CSS and HTML, not jQuery

Comment: Ahhh yes you are right. So basically, we have verified now that the `.signedin` class is being correctly but for some reason, `$('.signedin').css("margin-right","50px !important");` does not change the styles of that class. I will double check my CSS and HTML. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

you can try this long method :D

Make a style on specific class and you can add the attribute on that div if another element is visible.

For example,

```
.add-margin-50px{
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

> if($('.collapsed-sidebar').is(":visible")){
>   $(".signedin").addClass("add-margin-50px") 
>   }

Hope this can help :)

Comment: Ah yes. I was about to put an answer to my question and I used the same approach! :)

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't found the reason why `$('.signedin').css("margin-right","50px !important");` does not work so after doing some digging, I found another approach which is similar to @emjr's answer above. This approach makes use of `addClass()` and `removeClass()` of JQuery.

So in my CSS, I added custom styles for increasing/decreasing the margin when the sidebar is collapsed or not.

```
.signedin {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  &.collapsed {
    margin-right: 100px !important;
  }
  &.uncollapsed {
    margin-right: 300px !important;
  }
}
```

Then in my JS:

```
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function(){
  $('.openbtn').on('click', function() {
    $('.ui.sidebar').toggleClass('very thin icon');
    $('.collapsed-sidebar').toggleClass('displaynone');

    if($('.collapsed-sidebar').is(":visible")){
      $('.signedin').addClass('collapsed').removeClass('uncollapsed');
    }else{
      $('.signedin').addClass('uncollapsed').removeClass('collapsed');
    }
  });
});
```

Then in my HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="ui sidebar vertical left menu visible very thin icon">
        <div class="collapsed-sidebar displaynone"> // This is the element that I toggle
             // Sidebar content here
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pusher">
        <div class="row content">
            <div class="signedin uncollapsed">
                // The uncollapsed class here is what is being removed and replaced
                //by collapsed and vice-versa depending on the state of the sidebar.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body
```

So what happens is that it adds/removes the collapsed/uncollapsed classes as I toggle my sidebar.

I would still appreciate if anyone can figure out why the `.css()` approach didn't work and can point me to the right direction on that one.